# Updating Local Storage

Tags: javascript

I have a struggle with updating Local Storage values. I have "users" array from which I want to update my Local Storage, buy many problems have occured durning implementation. Please see code below, and also take note its only learning so dont be scared I use local storage for stroing login and password.

```
class Register {
    constructor({
        inputLogin,
        inputPassword
    }) {
        this.inputLogin = inputLogin;
        this.inputPassword = inputPassword;
    }

    users = [];

    add() {

        const btn = document.querySelector('#register-form__submit');
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const usersData = {
                login: this.inputLogin.value,
                password: this.inputPassword.value
            }



            if (localStorage.getItem('users')) {

                   // // I dont know what to do here, I want to get existing value from local Storage. Put them back to array users and then set local storage with this old an new value... But I've encountered a lot of problems like nested arrays, overlooping etc. Please tell me guys how you would've done it.
            } else {
                this.users.push(usersData);
                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(this.users));
            }

        })

    }

}
```

---

EDIT: Working solution. I hope it helps sombeody who wants to practice and doesn't know databases yet.

```
 class Register {
        constructor() {
    
            this.inputLogin = document.getElementById('login')
            this.inputPassword = document.getElementById('password')
            this.users = []
    
        }
    
    
        add() {
    //checking if inputs are empty
            if (this.inputLogin.value === '' || this.inputPassword.value === '') {
                this.alert('Musisz wypełnić wszystkie pola')
            } else {

//creating object with users data
                let userData = {
                    login: this.inputLogin.value,
                    password: this.inputPassword.value,
                }
    
    
                if (window.localStorage.getItem('users')) {

//checking if there are any users in local storage
                    const existingData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('users'));
    
//looping through those values and checking if there is already such an user with this login.
                    for (let i = 0; i < existingData.length; i++) {
                        if (existingData[i].login === userData.login) {
                            if (document.querySelector('.red-alert')) {
                                return;
                            } else {
                                this.alert("user already exists");
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
//checking if this.users[] is empty(this happens after refreshing page or restarting browser of course
                            if (this.users.length === 0) {
                                existingData.map((obj) => {
                                    return this.users.push(obj);
                                })
                                this.users.push(userData);
                                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(this.users))
                                window.location.href = "index.html";
                            }
//checking if there is some data in this.users. That means page was not refreshed nor browser was restarted.

 else if (this.users.length > 0) {
                                this.users.push(userData);
                                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(this.users))
                                console.log(this.users);
                                window.location.href = "index.html";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
 else {
                    //success when there are no users at all in this.users[] and local storage is empty
                    this.users.push(userData);
                    localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(this.users))
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }
            }

     alert(text) {
            const par = document.createElement('p')
            par.classList.add('red-alert');
            par.textContent = text;
            document.querySelector('.register-form').appendChild(par)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never, ever use local storage to store actual passwords. Also, what kind of issues you have? What about just `users = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('users') );`?

Comment: "many problems have ocurred" does not help much in debugging an issue. you will have to share what problems exactly ocurred.

Comment: Your issue is not clear. Please elaborate what issue you are facing

Comment: Hi guys, please take look on my clarification below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check for the existing key and then update the value of the local storage. Have added in line comments for better understanding

```
// ..rest of the code 

// check if the local storage have any key by this na,e
const currStoredData = localStorage.getItem('users');
// if key esxist
if (currStoredData) {
  // push the existing value of the key in the array
  this.users.push(currStoredData);
  // set the new user data in the local storage
  localStorage.setItem(usersData)

} else {
  this.users.push(usersData);
  localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(this.users));
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the local storage only at the beginning and work with the object after.
Because the storage only saves strings, you need to parse the value as well.

```
class Register {
    constructor({
        inputLogin,
        inputPassword
    }) {
        this.inputLogin = inputLogin;
        this.inputPassword = inputPassword;
    }

    users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

    add() {

        const btn = document.querySelector('#register-form__submit');
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const usersData = {
                login: this.inputLogin.value,
                password: this.inputPassword.value
            }

            this.users.push(usersData);
            localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(this.users));
        })

    }

}
```